# Nodemon carrega index do diretório mas não abre o index

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Estou com um problema ao usar o Nodemon, sempre que inicia ou reinicia o servidor por ele ao invés de printar algo no console ou carregar uma página ele fica apenas no Index do diretório. Demora vários minutos até ele finalmente responder e carregar a página ou responder uma requisição de log no console.

[image]

Comment: Como vc está fazendo o comando do `nodemon`? Creio que esteja acontecendo isso pois vc não tem nenhum index na raiz do seu projeto ou não passa nenhum arquivo como parametro para o nodemon, ex: `nodemon ./server.js`

Comment: estou usando o comando "nodemon server.js". Tanto que no console ele inicia o server (eu mando printar a porta do servidor), mas demora uns minutos até ele responder qualquer requisição minha.

Estou usando express, hbs e helmet

Comment: Não sei se o problema pode ser o `nodemon`, na dúvida tenta usar o `live-server`. Só por garantia tentar usar o comando com `./`(não sei se irá ser diferente), assim: `nodemon ./server.js`...

Comment: Utilizar o " ./ " resolveu o problema pelo o que parece. Vou continuar a fazer mais testes enquanto programo mas muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Ele deve ter achado que `server.js` é um comando, então quando você colocou `./` deixou implícito que era um arquivo seu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Max Rogério respondeu nos comentários da pergunta, a falta de `./` antes do arquivo ou do caminho do .js a ser setado estava ocasionando o erro.
Para corrigir apenas adicione o `./` antes do arquivo. Ex: `nodemon ./server.js`